# WDIO8 and BrowserStack Slow Android Performance

Tags: android, automation, webdriver-io, browserstack

I make use of WebDriverIO to run a single test suite across multiple web browsers on devices/operating systems on BrowserStack. The issue is that the run duration on Android device browsers take much longer than other devices/operating systems. Android typically takes over 15min to complete whereas other devices/browsers are typically well under 10min. Below is my environment and an example of the capabilities I am using for an Android device. I would like to know if there is anyway to speed things up. I have noticed that finding elements seems to take the longest when using an xpath pointing to a grid to return a collection of 40+ elements.

WebdriverIO version: 8.3.5

Mode: WDIO Testrunner

If WDIO Testrunner, running sync/async: async

Node.js version: 16.19.0

NPM version: 8.19.3

Browser name and version: Chrome latest

Platform name and version: Samsung Galaxy S21, Android 11 (on browserstack)

```
{
      'appium:waitForIdleTimeout': 0,
      'bstack:options': {
        'deviceName': 'Samsung Galaxy S21',
        'osVersion': '11.0',
        'appiumVersion': '2.0.0',
      },
      'browserName': 'Galaxy S21, Android 11',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible because of the custom Appium version you are passing that is causing the delay.

Browserstack has default Appium versions for each device defined on their official documentation.

Here is a snapshot for your reference:
[Image showing default Appium version for the specified device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfwYq.png)

Here is a link for your reference: https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I see no difference between the different Appium versions. I actually had it as default at first but changed to 2.0.0 in the hopes that there would be more options to improve the speed.

Comment: This could then possibly be due to network latency caused by the increased number of network hops.